# A man has two packets of chewing gum, one in his left pocket and another in his right pocket.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Everytime he wants a gum, he randomly chooses one of the pockets and takes out one. To start with each packet has $N$ pieces.
Find the probability that when he finds that the chosen packet is empty, the other one contains x pieces.

Here is how I tried it:

Left and Right have equal chances of being selected.
We can choose $N$ of one packet and $N-x$ of another packet. And we can choose $N$ of one and $N-x$ of another in $\frac{(2N -x)!}{N!(N-x)!}$. This is multiplied with $0.5^{2N}$. 
Am I doing this right ? Please help

Comment: This is the calssical problem known as Banach's matchbox problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach's_matchbox_problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${2N-x-1 \choose N-1}0.5^{2N-x-1}$

So you are choosing $N-1$ picks when he pulled the same pocket as on the last pick, on the others he picks another pocket

Comment: Ok this explanation is simple enough. Thanks. I couldn't understand the explanation on Wikipedia

Comment: @testerpceSen I just realized that he finds out a pocket is empty. My solution was about how many pieces is in other pocket when he pulls the last piece from the first. And he doesn't realize there is no gums until he put hand back there. So your solution is correct but I'm glad I helped you understand it.